# Search with date picker in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I want to know how to search or filter with jquery date picker in angular?

I 've got that
the angular did't know the data that was insert by jquery.
and i have try bootstrap date picker,jquery date picker and html5 date input.

```
 From <select ng-model="search.fromsector" class="form-control">
                  <option value="RGN">RGN</option>
                  <option value="MDL">MDL</option>
                  <option value="NYU">NYU</option>
                  <option value="HEH">HEH</option>
                  <option value="LSH">LSH</option>
                  <option value="NDY">NDY</option>
                </select>

      To <select ng-model="search.tosector" class="form-control">
                  <option value="RGN">RGN</option>
                  <option value="MDL">MDL</option>
                  <option value="NYU">NYU</option>
                  <option value="HEH">HEH</option>
                  <option value="LSH">LSH</option>
                  <option value="NDY">NDY</option>
              </select>

      Date<input type="text" id="datepicker" ng-model="search.date" datepicker class="form-control" datepicker />
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below is the code uses datepicker and search on json:

http://jsfiddle.net/6432E/8/

In ng-repeat you need to pass the date to filter

```
<li ng-repeat="cs in consultations|filter:searchc_date">
```